English for '美术‘ and '艺术'
The Chinese for the English word art is 艺术, which includes all kinds of arts. But I've seen in China that the Chinese word 美术 is also translated to art, isn't this a bit of misleading? I believe 美术 is mostly about painting and a few other forms of visual arts, but art is much more broad. Is there a word that can accurately describe the Chinese 美术?

I'll match art=艺术, fine art=美术, according to my search result on Quora and Zhihu.

To cut a long story short, (as a workable guide in everyday usage), if you want to say "the arts" in general, or in a broad generic sense, use 艺术; but if you want to refer, specifically, to "visual, fine art", (paintings, drawings,), use 美术.

美术 has two meanings according to Modern Chinese Dictionary, 7th Edition:

造型艺术 (Visual arts/Plastic arts)。
专指绘画 (Specifically refers to painting)。

艺术 on the other hand:

用形象来反映现实但比现实有典型性的社会意识形态，包括文学、绘画、雕塑、建筑、音乐、舞蹈、戏剧、电影、曲艺等。(Use images to reflect reality, but with a more typical social ideology than reality, including literature, painting, sculpture, architecture, music, dance, drama, film, folk art, etc)
指富有创造性的方式、方法。(Refers to creative ways or methods)
形状或方式独特且具有美感。(Shapes or forms that are unique and have aesthetic appeal)

Therefore, 艺术 is a broad, umbrella term that covers all forms of art, while 美术 specifically refers to the fine or visual arts.

In Revised Mandarin Chinese Dictionary by Taiwan Academic Network, it provides essentially the same definitions as above for the words 藝術 and 美術, but with fewer definitions for the former.

IMO, 美术 is the Chinese name for "fine/visual arts", which are created primarily for aesthetic and intellectual purposes and judged for their beauty and meaningfulness, specifically, painting, sculpture, and architecture. 美术 is a main branch of 艺术.
艺术 is the Chinese name for "arts", which includes a broad range of human products that involve creative or imaginative talent, generally expressive of technical proficiency, beauty, emotional power, or conceptual ideas. In general, the universe of arts includes the visual arts and performing arts, such as theatre, dance, music, literature, film, and other media such as interactive media.


But I've seen in China that the Chinese word 美术 is also translated to art, isn't this a bit of misleading?

The answer is NO.
美术 is translated to art is right.
Such as:
an artist 翻译为中文是 美术家
a work of art 翻译为中文是 美术品
art lettering 翻译为中文是 美术字
an art gallery/museum 翻译为中文是 美术馆

Is there a word that can accurately describe the Chinese 美术?

The answer is Yes, maybe you can use painting for accurately describe the Chinese 美术.
Such as:
to teach children painting/art  翻译为中文是 给孩子们上美术课
如果你想的话，我感觉你可以用painting 表示美术，当然用art 表示美术也没有错。
art 既可以翻译为艺术，也可以翻译为美术，都没有错。

Longman Contemporary English-Chinese Dictionary says that an artist can also means a performer  in a show, such as an actor or singer 演艺人员（如演员或歌手）

@NanningYouth Yes, you are right, artist can mean a professional performer in music , dance , or the theatre. Usually a English word is not only have one meaning.
